# Error getting variables from files to int() in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a value from a variable inside some files, here is the code:

```
path = '/opt/log/...'
word = 'somevariable'

def enumeratepaths(path=path):
    paths = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            fullpath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
            paths.append(fullpath)
    return paths

def read_files(file):
    try:
        file_open = open(file, 'r')
        search = file_open.read()
        find = search.find(word)
        find_start = find + 7
        find_stop = find + 9
        result = int(search[find_start:find_stop])
        return int(result)
    finally:
        file_open.close()

def main():
    for files in enumeratepaths():
        read_files(files)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that some files don't have the variable inside, because some error occurred. IN this case, this script returns an error:

```
    result = int(search[find_start:find_stop])
ValueError: invalid literal for int(): RE
```

I want to get these values as `int`, but I'm stuck.

And another question: If the file does not have that search value, how can it be that it returns things like "RE"?

Comment: do you have a sample of the file that is outputting the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `find` can't find the string you are searching for, it will return -1. So you can check the return value of `search.find(word)` to see if `word` was actually found.

At the moment you just proceed even if the searched word as not found. `find_start` will end up as 6, `find_end` as 8, and probably `search[6:8]` contains the characters "RE", which leads to the error message you see.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, i just proceed anyway, and got that RE'

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it like this:

```
try:
    int(somestring)
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    pass # not an int... what do you want to do now?
```

Or if you're always checking a string that should be digit only:

```
if somestring.isdigit():
```

Comment: Please switch the order.  The cleaner solution should be first.

Comment: @S.Lott: fair enough, I've changed it :)